# My static files in django are not getting reloaded unless i rename them every time i reboot my pc

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am trying to work on a django project which has static files. Every time I reload my pc and make some changes in the static files those changes don't get applied. Then i rename that static file and also change the static url in my template..Then the change takes place..How can i solve this..

Comment: HI Pranil, did you tried restarting your Django server?

Comment: yes i did that..

Comment: looks like cache issue, try clearing cache or open in incognito mode

Comment: opening in incognito mode does solve the issue but i have to login again...Is there a way that doesn't involve logging again..@zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your browser cache, and next time onwards when you made any changes to static files, do `Ctrl + Shift + R` to ignore previous cached content.

Comment: i am very sorry sir i did upvote your answer but since my reputation is less than 15 it isn't shown publicly